# Google Maps Data Layer, Click on geometry programmatically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I have a google map where I load geometry data to the data layer using geoJSON. I bind to the following event in the data layer.

```
map.data.addListener('click', function (event) { console.log(event);});
```

How can I trigger this event manually? I know I can trigger the click event on a marker manually, but it is triggered through `google.maps.event`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have the same problem.

Comment: I couldn't get the click event to trigger manually. By clicking a geometry what I did was taking the geometry feature and mess about with its style and show markers within that geometry. So I factored out that functionality into a separate method which took the feature as a parameter. Then when I wanted to manually trigger the event, I searched for the feature with 'map.data.getFeatureById(featureid)' and called the factored out method with it. Then it looked like as if the click event was triggered manually.

Answer (score 2):

That should be done with google.maps.event.trigger.

Try this (not sure):

```
// invoke a click
google.maps.event.trigger(map.data, 'click');
```

Answer (score 0):

While Emmanuel's answer is technically correct, I would like to expand on it because I struggled for 2-3 hours to get this working.
In my code, I have a predefined click event function which was using feature object.
Here is my click event where I have used feature object:

```
        transLayerData.addListener('click', function (event) {
          var lfeature = event.feature;
          var html = lfeature.getProperty('popupInfo');
          infowindow.setContent(html);
          infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
          infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,-34)});
          infowindow.open(myMap);
        });
```

If you are using a feature object in your predefined data layer click function (like above) , it is important that you pass the feature object and you create an event object with feature object in it.
Here is my code which gets the lat and long out of feature object and creates an event object:

```
            var featureGeometry = feature.getGeometry();
            var lsType = featureGeometry.getType();
            var isLineData = false;
            var lsType = featureGeometry.getType();
            if ((lsType == 'LineString') || (lsType == 'MultiLineString') || (lsType == 'LinearRing') || (lsType == 'Polygon') | (lsType == 'MultiPolygon')) {
                isLineData = true;
            }
            var featurePosition;
            if (isLineData) {
                // will center the map on the first vertex of the first LineString
                var tmp = featureGeometry.getAt(0);
                featurePosition = featureGeometry.getAt(0);
             // following will set line's storke weight to 10
                feature.setProperty('strokeWeight', 10);
            } else{
                featurePosition = featureGeometry.get();
            }
            myMap.setZoom(10);
            myMap.setCenter(featurePosition);
            var llat = featurePosition.lat();
            var llong = featurePosition.lng();

          // Creating event with the feature object is important. Especially if you have your very own feature click method defined
            var lEvent = {
                stop: null,
                latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(llat, llong),
                feature: feature,
            }

           // transLayerData is your data layer object. 
           // This is how I have defined my translayer object:
           // transLayerData = new google.maps.Data({ map: myMap });
            if (!isLineData) {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(transLayerData, 'click', lEvent);
                } else {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(transLayerData, 'mouseover', lEvent);
                }
            }
```